# MagicalRecord saveWithOption cause deadlock in release version

Tags: core-data, deadlock, restkit-0.20, magicalrecord

I use RestKit to post a Doctor object to server, then I save the object in the success block.
In the debug version, it works well for me. Even in release version(I use in-house to release), most of time it works well too. And when the deadlock happened, it will always happened whatever I kill the app and restart it.
But when I delete and reinstall it(use same version), it works fine again. It is so strange that I can not understand!
I use the latest of RestKit(0.23.3) and MagicalRecord(2.2) in CocoaPods.
Here is the code bellow:

```
[[AccountManager cloudDataManager] postWithData:self path:path control:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, id data) {
            self.doctorId = [data valueForKey:DoctorsAttributes.doctorId];
            [[self managedObjectContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                NSAssert(error == nil, ([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", error]));
                if (handler != NULL) {
                    handler();
                }
            }];
        } error:self.error failure:self.failureWithNotice];
```

And here is the error message:

```
Date/Time:           2014-08-26 11:16:43.368 +0800
OS Version:          iOS 7.1.2 (11D257)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
com.cvte.visiomed.inhouse.bewellConnect failed to resume in time

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 12.360 (user 12.360, system 0.000), 62% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 4.927, 25% CPU

Thread 0:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3902c627 objc_msgSend + 7
1   Foundation                      0x2f1af029 -[NSError dealloc] + 57
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x39031b67 objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 171
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x390320cf (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 355
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2e7bf47d _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 13
5   Foundation                      0x2f1b98df -[NSAutoreleasePool drain] + 119
6   CoreData                        0x2e5fffbb -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 939
7   BeWellConnect                   0x002a6c27 0xc6000 + 1969191
8   CoreData                        0x2e6639cb developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 87
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x3950bd3d _dispatch_client_callout + 21
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x3950e6bf _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 275
11  CoreFoundation                  0x2e85663d __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 5
12  CoreFoundation                  0x2e854f09 __CFRunLoopRun + 1305
13  CoreFoundation                  0x2e7bf725 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 521
14  CoreFoundation                  0x2e7bf507 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 103
15  GraphicsServices                0x3371e6cf GSEventRunModal + 135
16  UIKit                           0x3112086d UIApplicationMain + 1133
17  BeWellConnect                   0x0013716f 0xc6000 + 463215
18  libdyld.dylib                   0x39520ab5 start + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This will occur when my core data model is change.

Before setup MR, we should called `[MagicalRecord setShouldDeleteStoreOnModelMismatch:YES];`

Because MR will not delete data in release version in default